# how can I solve python numpy date and time ValueError

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scikit-learn

I have these lines of codes:

```
import numpy as np
f = open("scikit.csv")
f.readline() # skip the header
data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=",")
```

and first 5 rows of `scikit.csv`, are like bellow:

```
Date,Time,CPUUtilization_Average,CPUUtilization_Target,NetworkIn_Average,NetworkIn_Target,NetworkOut_Average,NetworkOut_Target,MemoryUtilization_Average,MemoryUtilization_Target,Final_Target,Final_Class
2017-12-07,16:55:00,17.0,low,0.0,low,0.0,low,5.47756198097301,low,10.312904877501694,low
2017-12-07,16:56:00,11.0,low,0.0,low,0.0,low,34.1503819977678,low,22.492003834477718,low
2017-12-07,16:57:00,3.0,low,0.0,low,0.0,low,34.2944535011255,low,19.045624937577248,low
2017-12-07,16:58:00,2.0,low,0.0,low,0.0,low,34.2875445714863,low,18.601948615438673,low
```

I want to use `sklearn` libraries and because my dataset is external, I am trying to use `numpy` related to [this (Loading from external datasets)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#loading-from-external-datasets) guide.

but I will get error when I want to convert my CSV to Python object using numpy in `np.loadtxt("scikit.csv", delimiter=",")`.
it will show this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Date
```

if I change the code like this:

```
data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter="," ,dtype="datetime64")
```

it will show another error on `time` column like bellow:

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "Date" at position 0
```

can you please guide me how I should solve this problem on `Date` and `Time` columns?

there is no force to use `numpy`.

Comment: Skip the first line. You trying to parse the header.
Your trying to parse every field as a datetime.

Comment: @digitalsentinel same error without header

Comment: Exactly?  Maybe first try converting a single datetime to date64

Comment: @digitalsentinel how?

Comment: You have a mixture of datatypes in this sample data (dates, strings, floats). When you specify dtype="datetime64", you are casting this datatype for the entire dataset. Also check out numpy's [genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways using numpy:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import dateutil.parser as dparser

print('option 1')
print(np.loadtxt('scikit.csv', dtype='object', skiprows=1, delimiter=',',
          converters={0: np.datetime64,
                              1: dparser.parse}))

print('option 2')
print(np.loadtxt('scikit.csv', dtype='object', skiprows=1, delimiter=',',
          converters={0: np.datetime64,
                              1: lambda t: time.strptime(t.decode('utf-8'),
                                                         '%H:%M:%S')}))

print('option 3')
print(np.loadtxt('scikit.csv', dtype='object', skiprows=1, delimiter=','))
```

Using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('scikit.csv', parse_dates=['Date', 'Time'])
                 #converters={'Date': np.datetime64, 'Time': lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H:%M:%S')})
```